# Rails Create hash from two other hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I have two hash `max` and `min` contain same key

max

```
{22479=>2018-05-24 20:15:11 UTC, 15392=>2018-04-24 09:38:32 UTC, 16319=>2018-04-27 02:21:53 UTC, 24644=>2018-06-07 20:01:04 UTC, 21551=>2018-05-19 20:11:11 UTC, 17876=>2018-05-03 15:47:54 UTC, 22467=>2018-05-24 17:11:15 UTC}
```

min

```
{22479=>2018-05-24 20:15:03 UTC, 15392=>2018-04-24 09:38:15 UTC, 16319=>2018-04-27 02:21:53 UTC, 24644=>2018-06-07 19:59:23 UTC, 21551=>2018-05-19 20:11:04 UTC, 17876=>2018-05-03 15:47:54 UTC, 22467=>2018-05-24 17:11:15 UTC}
```

I want to create the third hash with difference of those two hashes in terms of time. Like,

diff

```
{22479=> 9, 15392=> 17,.......}
```

Can anybody help me out for this, what is the efficient way of dong this.
Is have to iterate the loop two times.

Comment: Why is `2018-05-24 20:15:11 UTC - 2018-05-24 20:15:03 UTC` => `9`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Input

```
max
 => {22479=>2018-05-24 20:15:11 UTC,
     15392=>2018-04-24 09:38:32 UTC,
     16319=>2018-04-27 02:21:53 UTC,
     24644=>2018-06-07 20:01:04 UTC,
     21551=>2018-05-19 20:11:11 UTC,
     17876=>2018-05-03 15:47:54 UTC,
     22467=>2018-05-24 17:11:15 UTC}

min
 => {22479=>2018-05-24 20:15:03 UTC,
     15392=>2018-04-24 09:38:15 UTC,
     16319=>2018-04-27 02:21:53 UTC,
     24644=>2018-06-07 19:59:23 UTC,
     21551=>2018-05-19 20:11:04 UTC,
     17876=>2018-05-03 15:47:54 UTC,
     22467=>2018-05-24 17:11:15 UTC}
```

#### Solution

Fetch common keys from `max` and `min` and calculate the difference in time (in seconds).

```
(max.keys & min.keys).each_with_object({}) do |k, out|
  out[k] = (max[k] - min[k]).to_i
end
 => {22479=>8,
     15392=>17,
     16319=>0,
     24644=>101,
     21551=>7,
     17876=>0,
     22467=>0}
```

Comment: @DennyMueller: those are times, not strings

Comment: yep my bad, was testing it like 10 seconds ago. I was initially assuming that op has json hashes and not time object and your solution looked like you just subtracted the strings and I was like "wow you can just subtract the string"